# Can an Oracle test database import be done without adversely affecting the production Oracle instances?

Tags: oracle11gr2

On a production database, 11gR2, I have exported everything via Sql Developer, file.sql.  I just took all the defaults.

I have a test server with 11gR2 I am going to copy the .sql dump file over to.

Is there anything contained in a export, the one with everything in it, all the objects, data, and so on, that would cause problems for *the production* environment when I import the data into the *test* environment?

In other words, I don't want to break my production.  I don't have tnsnames.ora set up on my test.  I only want the schema, data, all the rest mentioned.

EDIT:

SELECT * FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_WINDOWS;

Showed nothing active.

DBA_JOBS

shows APEX jobs about the mail, stock jobs I think.  One about, EMD_MAINTENANCE.EXECUTE_EM_DBMS_JOB_PROCS();

SELECT * FROM DBA_DB_LINKS;

There is a link.  But, I know what it is from and it is no longer being used.

Thanks for the info you gave.  I feel better now.

Comment: Are you talking about separate servers - physical or virtual? Any shared disk (including SAN)? Is there any connection at all between the two environments? The only things I can think of that might even allow an issue if they are otherwise separate are database links or jobs which call out to remote resources, e.g. web services or http/ftp requests. If anything like that exists it could run in test but connect to the same thing as live, which would probably be bad. only you can know that though...

Comment: Totally different computers.  Are those items you mentioned in an export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard things I would think of are:

- use another system (not the same VM/server as production)
- disable all DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS and don't enable them back until you review their code
- disable all DBA_JOBS and don't enable them back until you review their code
- point DBA_DB_LINKS (both public and private database links) from the production databases to corresponding test databases or delete them; these sometimes use tnsnames.ora, but sometimes bypass it.

Comment: Would I be able to see these in the database itself, in one of the v$ tables?

Comment: These are not in V$ views, but in SYS.DBA_* ones. I've edited my answer to contain their names explicitly.

Comment: Configure the test database so it can't send email -- unless you need to test this too. Then check for stored procedures sending email -- it's very embarrassing to have to email again telling customers to ignore the previous email -- not to mention possibly even illegal in some countries to use their details in this way.